# Proof details of the fact that the unit tangent bundle is compact in $TM$ if $M$ is a compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, tangent-bundle

Let $M$ to be a manifold $m$-dimensional with a smooth hermitian metric $g$. The tangent bundle of $M$ is given by $TM= \bigcup_{p\in M} T_{p}M$, and the unit tangent bundle is given by

$S=\{x \in TM: \|x\|_{g(p)}  =1$ where $x \in T_{p}M\} $.

**(1)**

In [If M is a compact manifold, how to prove that the unitary tangent bundle is also compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2483666/if-m-is-a-compact-manifold-how-to-prove-that-the-unitary-tangent-bundle-is-al), the solutions assumed that given  $x$ in $M$, you can obtain $U$  open  neighborhood of $x$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U) \cap S \cong U \times S^{n-1}$. But this step is very important, and they do not show this homeomorphism.

**(2)**

In ["The unit ball fibration in a tangent bundle"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23240/the-unit-ball-fibration-in-a-tangent-bundle),  Pete L. Clark showed that $S$ is a compact set of $TM$ if $M$ is a compact manifold $m$-dimensional:

*"1) Do the problem in the special case that the ball fibration is trivial, i.e., isomorphic to a product.*

*2) Convince yourself that the ball fibration is locally trivial.*

*3) Since the base is compact, you can find a finite open cover $\{U_i\}$ such that the restriction of the fibration to each $U_i$ is trivial.  Now use the fact that a finite union of compact sets is compact."*

I was trying to understand this answer, but  I failed to follow this steps.

First of all, we consider $\pi: TM \to M$ the canonical projection. Using that $M$ is a compact  manifold, there exists a finite charts $(\phi_{i}, U_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ that covers $M$.

We note that if $M$ is a compact manifold then $TM$ is a trivial bundle, just consider $\Phi: TM \to M \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$ given by  $x \mapsto (\pi(x), \theta_{\pi(x)}^{(U_{i}, \varphi_{i})} (x)) $ where $\theta_{\pi(x)}^{(U_{i}, \varphi_{i})}:  T_{\pi(x)} M \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is a isomorphism linear and $i = \min\{j : \pi(x) \in U_{j}\}$.

But I'm stuck in this part. Can some one give some hint?

Thank you

---

Recall the definition:

**A vector bundle of rank $m$ over $M$** is a topological space $E$ together with a surjective continuous map $\pi:E \to M$ satisfying the following conditions:

($1$) For each $p \in M$, the fiber $E_{p}= \pi^{-1}(p)$ over $p$ is endowed with the structure of a $k$-dimensional real vector space.

($2$) For each $p$ in $M$, there exists a neighborhood U of p in M and a homeomorphism $\Phi: \pi^{-1}(U) \to U \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$ (called a **local trivialization of $E$ over $U$**), satisfying the following conditions:

(2.1) $\pi_{U} \circ \Phi = \pi$  (where $\pi_{U}:U\times \mathbb{R}^{m} \to U$ is the projection);

(2.2) for each $q$ in $U$, the restriction of $\Phi$ to $E_{q}$ is a vector space isomorphism from $E_{q}$ to $\{q\}\times\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

---

Comment: Or someone know where I can find this proof? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For your problem with **(1)**, the identification is provided by any orthonormal frame $e : U \times \mathbb R^m \to TM:$ the unit sphere bundle is exactly the image of $U \times S^{m-1}.$

Comment: I do not understand this argument. For consider a local frame from $U\times \mathbb{R}^{m}$ to $TM$, we will have to define our projection as $\widehat{\pi}: TM \to M \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$ (where $m$ is the dimension of manifold $M$), here $\widehat{E} =M \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$. So $U \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is an open set in $M \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$.

Comment: But in this case, for a point $(p,v)$ in $U \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$, we have that  $\widehat{E}_{(p,v)} = (\widehat\pi)^{-1}(p,v)= v$ where $v \in T_{p}M$, and then ($\widehat{\pi}, TM , M \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$)  is a  vector bundle of rank 1 over $M \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$.  In this case, the local frame $TM$ over $U \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$ consists of one function and therefore  it do not span $T_{p}M$.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted me. I simply mean to take an orthonormal frame $e_1,\ldots,e_m$ (where each $e_i$ is a vector field on $U$) and consider it as a map $e : U \times \mathbb R^m \to TM$ by sending the $k^{\rm th}$ standard basis vector to $e_k$; i.e. $e(p,\delta_k) = e_k(p)$ where $\delta_k$ is the standard (or any orthonormal) basis of $\mathbb R^m.$

Comment: But where I can find the "Gram-Schmit Algorthm for frames"? I know only in the context that $U$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for $E = T\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: I was looking the proof of Gram-Schmit Algorthm for frames in Lemma 8.13 of Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds", and apparently, we can use the same argument to prove Gram-Schmit for frames in general  manifolds.

Comment: It's not true, that for $M$ compact $TM$ is trivial.